# Is it possible to have Typeorm to use an entity/migration to generate a table

Tags: typeorm

My question is it is possible to use an entity as a blueprint to create database tables using Typeorm migrations instead of having to redefine the structure on the migration file. I don't want to use synchronize = true, I want to have migrations to define my database structure because it's a better practice. For example

something like this.

```
@Entity()
export class Product
{
}

migration:
queryRunner.createTable(new Table(Product)); //one line creation

Instead of having to write the complete table in the migration file


 queryRunner.createTable(new Table({

    name: 'product',
    column: [{
      name: 'column1',
      type: 'int'
    },
    {
      name: 'column1',
      type: 'int'
    },
 ....
    {
      name: 'column30',
      type: 'int'
    }]

 })
```

My desire is to use the definition on the entity class, which is much cleaner.